# Error for the keyword BETWEEN in a query

Tags: java, sql, derby

Why is there an error near the between keyword, namely

```
Error code -1, SQL state 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "BETWEEN" at line 10, column 34.
```

Any ideas why that would happen?

```
select c.CustomerCode AS 会员ID, c.LastName || ' ' ||  c.FirstName AS 姓名, c.MobilePhoneNumber AS 手机号码 from  
    customer  c  
    where  
    case when
    cast( { fn  TimeStampAdd(SQL_TSI_YEAR, (YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) - YEAR(c.DOB)), c.DOB) }  as date) < CURRENT_DATE
    then
    { fn  TRIM(CAST(CAST(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)+1 AS CHAR(4)) AS VARCHAR(4))) } || '-' ||
    { fn TRIM(CAST(CAST(MONTH(c.DOB)  AS CHAR(2)) AS VARCHAR(2))) } || '-' ||
    { fn TRIM(CAST(CAST(DAY(c.DOB) AS CHAR(2)) AS VARCHAR(2))) }
          BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE
          AND cast ({ fn  TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_DAY,  +7 ,   CURRENT_DATE) } as date)   
    else
    { fn  TRIM(CAST(CAST(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) AS CHAR(4)) AS VARCHAR(4)))} || '-' ||  
    { fn TRIM(CAST(CAST(MONTH(c.DOB)  AS CHAR(2)) AS VARCHAR(2))) } || '-' ||
    { fn TRIM(CAST(CAST(DAY(c.DOB) AS CHAR(2)) AS VARCHAR(2))) }
          BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE
          AND cast ({ fn  TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_DAY,  +7 ,   CURRENT_DATE) } as date)   
    end
    group by c.CustomerCode, c.LastName, c.FirstName, c.MobilePhoneNumber;
```

Comment: `会员ID` is not a legal SQL identifier you need to enclose it with double quotes: `"会员ID"`

Comment: Hi there, I remove the alias, but the problem persists

Comment: What DB are you using?

Comment: I am using JavaDB/Derby Thanks

Comment: Note that when there is no conditions in the clause. It works as expected

Answer (score 0):

I put a braces around the date/time clause, that solves it